# Can I use PSFTP to connect?

Tags: ftp, sftp, psftp

I can connect to a FTP site using FileZilla.  It uses the FTP Protocol, requiring implicit FTP over TLS, username, password, and uses a passive transfer mode, on port 900.

I am trying to find a command line utility that will let me test whether the site is up or down.  After doing some research it looks like PSFTP will work, but Im not having success.

Im trying to use [PSFTP](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) to connect to the site, but failing.  Does PSFTP support these methods?  If so, how?  If not, what does?

In the end, I simply want to monitor whether the site is up or down.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, PuTTY only supports SSH and the `psftp` tool is for SFTP, the SSH file transfer protocol. It does not support any kind of FTPS (FTP-over-TLS). (However, [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) has FTPS support.)

Comment: This worked.  Now I can script something to test the site.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

psftp is SSH-FTP.  Not FTP.  They are different protocols.  If you are looking for a command line client I strongly suggest you take a look at [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/).  It is available on most platforms, and supports ftps

Here is a usage example of curl for ftps I found, that might be helpful. http://www.unixlore.net/articles/using-curl-for-ftp-over-ssl-file.html